# Loop through nodes collection in Groovy

Tags: loops, groovy, graph-theory

I have map of names or nodes in groovy where key os parent and value is dependent on the parent childs.

```
'A' -> 'B', 'C'
'B' -> 'C'
'C' -> 'D'
'D'
```

The node which doesn't have leafs is not specified as key in map.

I need to specify ranking for every of the node based on their level. It means I would like create new map or change existing where it will contain the rank starting with 100 for nodes which doesn't have leafs.

```
'D' -> 100
'C' -> 101
'B' -> 102
'A' -> 103
```

What is best way to do it in groovy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this (runs on `GroovyConsole`)

```
//the list of nodes
def nodes = ['A','B','C','D']
//the map of children for each node(children are in lists)
def children = [A:['B', 'C'],B:['C'],C:['D']]
//the map for the rankings
def ranking = [:] 

//define closure first so it can be called recursively
def calculate
calculate = {
    if(children.containsKey(it)){
        //if key is in children map it has children -> at least rank 1
        int rank = 1
        //get children ranks and put it con collection
        def childrenRanks = children[(it)].collect{calculate(it)}
        //add max children rank to parent rank and return
        return rank + childrenRanks.max()
    }else{
        //if key is not on children map is leaf so rank 0
        return 0
    }
}

nodes.each{
    ranking[it] = 100 //fixed value
    ranking[it] += calculate(it)
}

println ranking
```

Comment: Alfergon, thank you. What is children:children? How I can read it?

Comment: @yart It is a map constructor. Groovy provides these by default. It means: "start the `children` field with the value in the `children` variable"

Comment: Exactly what @WillP says :D Is this example enough? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Alfergon, it works on this data but I need to try on bigger data.
Calling new Calculator(children:children) is the same like new Calculator(children)?

Comment: @Alfergon, also question about why you have defined class but not haven't used closure with return value?

Comment: @yart new Calculator(children:children) is not the same as new Calculator(children) as the constructor for Calculator with a parameter is not defined (but you can define it if your prefer). I used a class for code cleanness but you could do the recursion using closures also.

Comment: @Alfergon, thank you. I had almost similar code. If you know, could you just provide sample how to make recursion with closure?